# Convert JSON to Array of strings

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, swifty-json

I'm looking for your help because I'm trying to convert my JSON to an Array of strings.

Actually I have my content like this :

```
var answers = JSON() {
    didSet {
        print(answers)

        //radioTableView.items = ["ans1", "ans2", "ans3"]

        radioTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

My print give me an output like this (as a good JSON) :

```
[
  "ans1",
  "ans2",
  "ans3"
]
```

My radioTableView.items is looking for an array of strings (to display my content nicely) but I can't find any way to convert my json as the right content that I'm looking for.

PS : I'm using SwiftyJSON.

Thank you for your help

Comment: You can use decodable. To get the `[items]` from JSON. If you are using `SwiftyJSON`, then there is a method called `json.array`, you can use it.

Comment: Thank you @Rob for your answer. It's almost there because I've got the content like this now : ```[ans1, ans2, ans3]```

I'm looking for getting an array of string, like the commented line in my starting post.

Thank you again for your help ;)

Comment: What is the current type of `[ans1, ans2, ans3]`?

Comment: The content is just strings

Comment: You can use `as? [String]`.

Comment: Tried by : Could not cast value of type 'SwiftyJSON.JSON' (0x100c7d038) to 'Swift.String' :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205663/discussion-between-rob-and-noxo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
radioTableView.items = answers.array!.map { $0.string! }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I'm getting this error : Value of type '[JSON]' has no member 'string'

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, if you would like to create structures from your JSON I found this handy site that will prepare the Swift Struct for you.  Note: I do not work for the site or have any reason for linking it, aside from the fact that I find it to be an awesome tool.

https://app.quicktype.io/

Comment: I just checked your link, It looks like really great ! I save it, It'll be useful in the future ;)